# Apply rotation and translation to bones(Math)

Tags: python

https://stackoverflow.com/q/38541723/2495562

I posted the question on stackoverflow ealier before I realised here might be the right place to ask blender related questions.

---

I'm using blender 2.49 because the script was originally written for that version.

I'm trying to create animations using some transform data.

The original data contains a sequence of joints. Each joint has its own rotation and translation values, it may or may not have a parent joint. This sounds pretty much like bones in blender, right?

**To set up the skeleton:**

```
#pseudocode
for joint in joints:
    v = Vector(0,0,0)
    j=joint
    while j:
        v = j.rotation*v
        v = v + j.location
        j = j.parent
    joint.position = v
```

**To process a certain frame:**

```
#pseudocode
for joint in joints:
    v = Vector(0,0,0)
    j=joint
    while j:
        rot=j.rotation+j.curFrame.dRotation
        loc=j.location+j.curFrame.dLocation
        v = rot*v
        v = v + loc
        j = j.parent
    joint.position = v
```

---

To make things simple, I convert each joint into a small bone.

```
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        bone = Blender.Armature.Editbone()
        bone.head = Mathutils.Vector(0,0,0)
        bone.tail = Mathutils.Vector(0,1,0)
        bone.name = 'Bone.' + str(i)
        bone.parent = armature.bones['Bone.' + str(bones[i].parent)]
        armature.bones[bone.name] = bone
```

Then I move the bones to their desired locations, using the posebone trick to create the skeleton:

```
    pose=armObject.getPose()
    pose_bones=pose.bones
    #pose the bones
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        tran = transforms[i]
        pose.bones[name].quat = Mathutils.Euler(tran.rotX,tran.rotY,tran.rotZ).toQuat()
        pose.bones[name].loc = Mathutils.Vector(tran.locX, tran.locY, tran.locZ)
    pose.update()
    #update editbones
    armature.makeEditable()
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        armature.bones[name].matrix = pose.bones[name].poseMatrix
    armature.update()
    #reset pose
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        pose.bones[name].quat = Mathutils.Euler(0,0,0).toQuat()
        pose.bones[name].loc = Mathutils.Vector(0,0,0)
    pose.update()
```

So far so good. But when I apply the transform to a certain frame, the results are incorrect.

```
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        tran = frame.dTransforms[i]
        pose.bones[name].quat = Mathutils.Euler(tran.rotX,tran.rotY,tran.rotZ).toQuat()
        pose.bones[name].loc = Mathutils.Vector(tran.locX, tran.locY, tran.locZ)
```

By incorrect I mean the rotations seem correct, but the translations are all wrong. I guess it is because the transforms should be applied to the posebone's local space(the skeleton is correct because all transforms start from the center )? But how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Well I solved the problem already. I realized the transforms are done in the bone's local space, so they need to be calculated with the editbone's matrix before applying to the posebone.

```
for i in range(0, len(bones)):
    name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
    tran = frame.dTransforms[i]
    pb = pose.bones[name]
    eb = armature.bones[name]
    m1 = eb.matrix['BONESPACE'].rotationPart()
    e1 = m1.toEuler()
    e = Mathutils.Euler(tran.rotX,tran.rotY,tran.rotZ)
    e2 = Mathutils.Euler(e1.x+e.x,e1.y+e.y,e1.z+e.z)
    m2 = e2.toMatrix()
    m = m2*(m1.copy().invert())
    pb.quat = m.toQuat()
    pb.loc = m1*Mathutils.Vector(tran.locX,tran.locY,tran.locZ)
```